# Readthedocs build: cmake/swig are not available

Tags: python, pip, read-the-docs

In order to build in readthedocs, I need to install some requirements. One of these pip requirements needs cmake and swig to build.

Is it still possible to use readthedocs in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is a filed issue about this already: https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/2094

It contains a workaround:

> For anyone else running into this it seems you can also hack around it using the ['READTHEDOCS' env var](http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-change-behavior-for-read-the-docs) to conditionally modify `install_requires` in your `setup.py`.

This points to:

> When RTD builds your project, it sets the `READTHEDOCS` environment variable to the string True. So within your Sphinx `conf.py` file, you can vary the behavior based on this. For example:

```
import os
on_rtd = os.environ.get('READTHEDOCS') == 'True'
if on_rtd:
    html_theme = 'default'
else:
    html_theme = 'nature'
```

OTOH, the last comment claims it should work fine with the current RTD version.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. There is an ongoing PR to add swig https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs-docker-images/issues/15 and also this point here http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#i-get-import-errors-on-libraries-that-depend-on-c-modules was quite useful.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then that last comment might be talking about near-future versions ;-) Btw. the other FAQ is right below the part where the workaround points to ...